# How to change detail band height dynamically depending to a table

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a detail band that contains a table, when the table has too much rows, the data stretchs up and exceeds the band and my report get messed up.

What is the best solution to set the detail band height dynamically, when the table has more data.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration for detail band works for me fine, can you give more details about your configuration and table size.

[image: detail band]

[image]